# PHP put values from CSV file into an array

Tags: php, arrays, fopen, fgetcsv, array-push

I have a CSV file with two columns. The first is an ID number and the second is the number of products with that ID. The CSV can have multiple copies of the same ID, and what I need to do is merge these and add the number of products for each ID together.

The CSV looks like this:

> 12345, 10
>   
> 12345, 5
>   
> 12345, 20
>   
> 67890, 1
>   
> 67890, 7
>   
> 67890, 2

And I need it to turn into:

> 12345, 35
>   
> 67890, 10

The way I have come up with to do this is to create a multidimentional array with an overall array containing the ID numbers, and each of those being an array containing the number of products. Then add up those values inside the arrays.

I am struggling to put the number of products into the ID arrays however. I am currently using this to create the array:

```
$unique = array();
$file = fopen('test.csv', 'r');

while($row = fgetcsv($file, 0, ',', '\\')) {
    $unique[$row[0]] = true;
    array_push($unique[$row[0]], $row[1]);
}
```

$row[0] is added to the array as a unique value, but when I try to push $row[1] into the ID array I get an error stating that the value is a boolean and not an array because for some reason $row[0] becomes a '1' instead of the ID when I try to use it in the array push.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The value is boolean because you're setting it as a boolean value (true). What you're offering to array_push is not an array, but "true" boolean value. And I don't think you understand how array_push works: it adds a value to the *end* of the array. It doesn't affect values already *in* the array. If you want to put a key / value pair into array use $array[$key] = $value. Then you can use the pair to increase it ($array[$key] += $value, for example).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the following:

```
$unique = array();
$file = fopen('test.csv', 'r');

while($row = fgetcsv($file, 0, ',', '\\')) {
    $unique[$row[0]][] = $row[1];
}
var_dump($unique);
```

This will provide the output like:

```
  12345 => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => string ' 10 ' (length=4)
      1 => string ' 5 ' (length=3)
      2 => string ' 20 ' (length=4)
  67890 => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => string ' 1 ' (length=3)
      1 => string ' 7 ' (length=3)
      2 => string ' 2' (length=2)
```

**Edit:** if you also want the sum of `$row[1]` you can try the following inside the loop:

```
$unique[$row[0]] = !isset($unique[$row[0]]) ? (int)$row[1] : $unique[$row[0]] + (int)$row[1];
```

Comment: If the provided solution was helpful. Please, be sure to accept it.

Answer (score 1):

`$unique[$row[0]]` is set to true in the line before.
If I read this correctly, that means that if `$row[0]` is `12345`, the `$unique` array will have the index `12345` filled with `true`.

I think you might want to use a [Multidimensional array](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_arrays_multi.asp) instead of a normal array?

Answer (score 0):

The problem you have is that your key is numeric and the array wants to be numeric in stead of a alphanumeric key.  If I face this kind of problem I like to sole it this way as a quick and dirty solution. Try this code in your loop.

```
$key = $row[0];
if (!array_key_exists("{$key}", $unique))
{
$unique["{$key}"] = $row[1];
}
else
{
$unique["{$key}"] += $row[1];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're setting $unique[$row[0]] to true the line above.

Try this:

```
<?php
$data = [];
$file = fopen('test.csv', 'r');
while($row = fgetcsv($file, 0, ',', '\\')) {
  $value = isset($data[$row[0]]) ? $data[$row[0]] : 0;
  $value += $row[1];
  $data[$row[0]] = $value;
}
print_r($data);
```

This prints the following on my machine:

```
Array
(
  [12345] => 35
  [67890] => 10
)
```

Which you could then write to a CSV with something like

```
foreach($data as $k => $v) {
  echo "$k,$v\n"; // Replace this with a file write obviously
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try below example for your question. Check first if array key exist or not. if key is not exist then assign 0 to that key then make sum of that key below the key exist condition.

```
$unique = array();
$file = fopen('test.csv', 'r');

while ($row = fgetcsv($file, 0, ',', '\\')) {
    if (!array_key_exists($row[0], $unique)) {
        $unique[$row[0]] = 0;
    }
    $unique[$row[0]] += $row[1];
}
echo "<pre>";
print_r($unique);
```

`$unique[$row[0]] += $row[1];` this line will give you unique index with sum of unique index.

Here is the out of the above code.

```
Array
(
    [12345] => 35
    [67890] => 10
)
```